# Add MenuItems to a ContextMenuStrip from SubItems of a ListView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview, contextmenustrip

My Form defines a ContextMenuStrip:

```
Dim CMS As New ContextMenuStrip
Button1.ContextMenuStrip = CMS
```

There is also a Listview with 5 columns and some data:

```
ListView1.View = View.Details
```

How can I display the content of SubItems at index `1` and K of the first `5` Items of this ListView in a ContextMenuStrip?

```
CMS.Items.Clear()
For i As Integer = 0 To 5
    Dim line As String = ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).Text
    Dim line1 As String = ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(3).Text
    CMS.Items.Add(line & "|" & line1)
Next i
```

If the ListView contains are less than `5` ListViewItems, I get an exception.
If there is one ListViewItem in the ListView, then create one MenuItem.
If there are more than 5 ListViewItems, then display only values from the first 5 Items.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an interval of values in different ways.
Using the Min/Max methods of the Math class is probably simple and it can adapted to different scenarios. Personally, I used it quite often to validate the Maximum and Minimum values of Properties (e.g., you have a Property of Type `Byte`, so you may want to accept only values between `0` and `255`).

- You want to retrieve values from SubItems of the first `5` Items of a ListView. This is the `Max()` value.
- The Min number of *elements* is determined by the content of the `Items` collection. It could be `0`: in this case we don't want to iterate that collection, since it has nothing to give back. So, `0` is the `Min()` value
- We need to consider that the indexer of these collections starts from `0`.

The range of values is then:

```
Math.Max(Math.Min([Items Number], 5), 0) - 1
```

`-1` since we start from `0`: if we want Max 5 values, we iterate from `0` to `(5 - 1)` and if the `Items` collection has `0` elements, we iterate from `0` to `(0 - 1)`, so we don't iterate the collection at all (the loop terminates right away).

You can rewrite your loop as:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Math.Max(Math.Min(ListView1.Items.Count, 5), 0) - 1
    Dim line As String = ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).Text
    Dim line1 As String = ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(3).Text
    CMS.Items.Add(line & "|" & line1)
Next i
```

Comment: but do not tell me how to get the last 5 records?

Comment: You asked to get the **first** 5 Items: your question was *If there are more than 5 lines, then display only the first 5 lines*.